# Chart and graphs

Tags: itext

I am using iTextSharp version 4.1.2 and cannot update to newer version because iText changed 
their licence agreement.
I am very satisfied with this version and it's working fine for me.

I can't find anywhere how to produce pie or bar or columns graphs and charts
with that version and looks like all documentation over the internet been removed.
If you are using older version and by the chance you have documentation can you please share
or point me to the source, or explain how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iText doesn't have built-in support for charts or graphs. Instead you are encouraged to use a 3rd-party library to generate these and then add them as either graphics or PDFs.

Another option as outlined in [this post](http://www.kunlesmart.com/post/2014/11/08/draw-pie-chart-in-itextsharp-with-pdfcontentbyte.aspx)  is to use the [iTextSharpExtensions](https://github.com/KunleSmart/iTextSharpExtensions). Please note that although it has the word "iText" in it is in no way endorsed by the makers of iText.

Also, as a quick side note, [please read FAQ](http://itextpdf.com/customer-faq), specifically the "*Why shouldn't I use iText 2.x (or iTextSharp 4.x)?*" explaining some of the myths of the license of the version you are using.