# Visual presentation of number in itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I want to put value (0 to 100) with visual presentation like the below image in iTextsharp. [image]

Can anyone help how to achive this? the round should show the percentage(74,12,70).

Comment: Have you tried something out?

Comment: @utility Yeah i tried with a fixed line with a image placing with respect to the number. Is there any chart or something simple than this?

Comment: Quoting Chris Haas: [_"iText doesn't have built-in support for charts or graphs. Instead you are encouraged to use a 3rd-party library to generate these and then add them as either graphics or PDFs."_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20378124/996081)