# output a graph from HTML with iText for .NET

Tags: c#, html, pdf, itext

I'm creating a pdf document from a html source, with iText for .NET, but I'm facing a problem. I have a graph in this document, that is built in HTML, but this is not showing in PDF output.

The HTML for the graph is:

```html
<table style="height:100;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <!-- BARS-->
    <tr style="height: 100">
      <td></td>
      <td valign="bottom" style="padding: 0 1px">
        <span>500</span>
        <div style="height:60%; background-color: black"></div>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td valign="bottom" style="padding: 0 1px">
        <span>500</span>
        <div style="height:20%; background-color: black"></div>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- AXIS-->
    <tr style="background-color:red; padding: 0; height: 2px">
      <td colspan="27">
        <div style="height:0;width:100%;border:0;border-bottom:2px;border-style: solid;border-color: #000000"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- MONTHS-->
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Ene</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Feb</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the C# code for creating pdf from html (this code works fine):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace PruebaITextSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER);
                iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
                document.Open();
                iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper helper = iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();

                string facturaHTML = File.ReadAllText("D:\\route\\to\\source.html");
                helper.ParseXHtml(writer, document, new StringReader(facturaHTML));
                writer.Flush();
                document.Close();

                FileStream file = new FileStream("output.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                file.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
                file.Flush();
                file.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `itextsharp` can do that. You may want to use **ItextSharpExtenions**. See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372118/chart-and-graphs

Comment: Another option : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/export-chart-to-pdf-using-itextsharp/

Comment: Try actually specifying your units. In two places you have `height:100;` but you actually want `height:100px;` or `height:100%;` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally this works for me!

```html
<!-- GRAPH -->
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <!--BARS-->
  <tr>
    <td width="100%">
      <table width="100%" style="" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
          <tr style="font-size:5pt;height:130px;">
            <!-- -->
            <td style="font-size:5pt;width:4%"></td>
            <!-- MONTH 1 -->
            <td valign="bottom" style="font-size:5pt;width:5%">
              <p valign="center" style="width:100%; height:8px;">label 1</p>
              <div style="width:100%; height:20px; background-color:black">
              </div>
            </td>
            <!-- -->
            <td style="font-size:5pt;width:2%"></td>
            <!-- MONTH 2 -->
            <td valign="bottom" style="font-size:5pt;width:5%">
              <p valign="center" style="width:100%; height:8px;">label 2</p>
              <div style="width:100%; height:10px; background-color:gray">
              </div>
            </td>
            <!-- -->
            <td style="font-size:5pt;width:2%"></td>
            <!-- MONTH 3 -->
            <td valign="bottom" style="font-size:5pt;width:5%">
              <p valign="center" style="width:100%; height:8px;">label 3</p>
              <div style="width:100%; height:30px; background-color:gray">
              </div>
            </td>
            <!-- -->
            <td style="font-size:5pt;width:2%"></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- AXIS -->
  <tr style="background-color:black; padding: 0; height: 1px">
    <td colspan="26" nowrap="" >
      <div></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- MONTHS LABELS -->
  <tr>
    <td width="100%">
      <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="4%"></td>
          <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="5%">month 1</td>
          <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="2%"></td>
          <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="5%">month 2</td>
          <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="2%"></td>
          <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="5%">month 3</td>
          <td style="font-size:5pt;" width="2%"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```